# Rest API Custom Endpoint with space character

Tags: rest-api, endpoints

I'm trying to add an endpoint with the following:

```
register_rest_route('namespace/v1','custom-search/(?P<search>[a-zA-Z\s]+)',
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'gm_custom_search_callback'
        )
    );
```

It registers the route, but won't recognise when I add a space character i.e. %20 or pass a string with a " " in, I can't see anywhere that would suggest how this should be achieved, am I missing something?

Comment: use placeholders - like ```-``` or something more unique in the passed search parameter - just make sure the placeholder is allowed in the endpoint regex - then replace these before passing the value to the callback method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this:

```
function get_custom_search_callback($request) {
    //$parameters = $request->get_params();
    $response = urldecode($request->get_param('search'));

    return rest_ensure_response($response);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');
function add_custom_users_api(){
    register_rest_route('namespace/v1',
                        'custom-search/(?P<search>([a-zA-Z]|%20)+)',
                        array(
                            'methods' => 'GET',
                            'callback' => 'get_custom_search_callback'
                        )
                    );
}
```

Note two things:

- you have to add `%20` to the matched character set
- you have to `urldecode()` the `search` variable value to get rid of the `%20` and possibly other urlencoded characters (if you put it in the regex)